# Primefaces <p:selectOneMenu> compoment null pointer exception

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

**thanks for any suggestions.**

I i'm trying to use primefaces  component when i select element and proceed getting null pointer exception due to contractid, which can not be null because i have already initiated this.
Here is the code.

```xml
<h:selectOneMenu id="ContractName" value="#{managedContract.c.contract_id}" style="width: 300px;" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Select Contract.">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="-Select Contract-" noSelectionOption="true" itemDisabled="true"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItems value="#{managedContract.contracts}" var="contractvar" itemLabel="#{contractvar.contract_name}" itemValue="#{contractvar.contract_id}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

```java
public class ManagedContract{
   private int contractid;
   public managedContract(){
   this.contractid=0;


//getter

//setter

//....

}
```

Answer (score 1):

romove `var="contractvar" itemLabel="#{contractvar.contract_name}" itemValue="#{contractvar.contract_id}"` from `<f:selectItems>`

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="ContractName" value="#{managedContract.c.contract_id}" style="width: 300px;" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Select Contract.">
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="-Select Contract-" noSelectionOption="true" itemDisabled="true"></f:selectItem>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{managedContract.contracts}"  />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

and in your bean you must have  `getContracts()` method

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ManagedContract imlements java.io.Serializable{
   private int contractid;
   public managedContract(){
   this.contractid=0;
}

//getter

//setter

//....

}
```

Comment: @user2834146 if it works fine accept  my answer or upvote it  to lead others to the correct answer

Comment: Nothe that this solution depends on the `f:selectItems` implementation at the managed bean and the POJO implementation itself. The POJO must return its id when calling `toString()` method, which the OP doesn't mention. Otherwise, you need to directly use a converter.